# Twitter Sentiment Analysis in German

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I tried this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSOUd9Sm1gI&t=1090s) to make a Twitter sentiment analysis. As soon as I change the language from 'en' to 'de', the analysis doesn't work. When I try to debug it, it shows that it finds the rights tweets, but the analysis can't sort them into positive or negative. Why is this?

This is my code:

```
import tweepy
import textblob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

authenticator = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
authenticator.set_access_token(bearer, bearer_secret)

api = tweepy.API(authenticator, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


search = f'#afd -filter:retweets'
tweet_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search, lang = 'de', tweet_mode='extended').items(1000)
tweets = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_cursor]

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Tweets'])

for _, row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    row['Tweets'] = re.sub ('http\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['Tweets'] = re.sub ('#\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['Tweets'] = re.sub ('@\S+', '', row['Tweets'])
    row['Tweets'] = re.sub ('\\n+', '', row['Tweets'])

tweets_df['Polarity'] = tweets_df['Tweets'].map(lambda tweet:textblob.TextBlob(tweet).sentiment.polarity)
tweet:textblob.TextBlob(tweet).sentiment.subjectivity)
tweets_df['result'] = tweets_df['Polarity'].map(lambda pol : '+' if pol > 0 else '-')

positive = tweets_df[tweets_df.result=='+'].count()['Tweets']
negative = tweets_df[tweets_df.result=='-'].count()['Tweets']

plt.bar([0, 1], [positive, negative], label= ['Positive', 'Negative'], color=['green', 'red'])
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

I tried to change the language to en with my searchers, and then it works, but he uses English tweets that I don't.

Comment: Probably due to TextBlob. You may need to get the German Extension, but not 100% sure if this extension accommodates sentiment polarity and subjectivity: https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/extensions.html

Comment: That was a huge help thank you alot! But i dont know how to use this in my code :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are using a lexicon based sentiment analysis. Meaning the lexicon is a long list of words someone has once assigned a negative or positive value to.
So for example:
Wonderful = positive = +1
Awful = negative = -1
When the analysis is run in English you get a valid result because the words are in the lexicon. However when you use German, the words are not in the Lexicon. You have to use a german lexicon.
Viel Glück! :)

Comment: Greetings! While the logic here makes sense, it may be better to show with some code why this is the case. Otherwise this answer seems like pure speculation.